# Mongoose/Express Update Route Cast to Object ID issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

Working with Express and Mongoose, and I'm writing an Update route, and I seem to have hit a wall with this route. I've tried to find the object being requested via:

```
router.patch('/:insiderId', (req, res) => {
  Insider.findById(req.params.insiderId)
    .then(insider => {
      insider = Object.assign({}, insider, req.body);
      insider
        .save()
        .then(updated => {
          res.json(updated);
        })
        .catch(err =>
          res
            .status(400)
            .json({ error: 'error updating insider', originalError: err })
        );
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(400).json({
        error: 'error finding insider to update.',
        originalError: err
      });
    });
});
```

But I'm still given an error stating that `Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"5b16d9e9119bef28908f49c\" at path \"_id\" for model \"insiders\"`

I did a little reading, and thought that `findById` would automatically cast the objectid, but it doesn't appear to be doing that.

Is my code wrong?

Comment: Use the built-in method `findByIdAndUpdate` http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findbyidandupdate_findByIdAndUpdate

Comment: Okay, I'll look into that now!